# customize cc_library to add params check

Tags: bazel-cpp

as per example
https://github.com/bazelbuild/examples/tree/main/configurations/cc_binary_selectable_copts

I would like to customize the cc_libarry
I wrote sample implementation

```
def _library_transition_rule_impl(ctx):
    actual_library = ctx.attr.actual_library[0]
    print("actual_library {}".format(actual_library))

    outfile = ctx.actions.declare_file(ctx.label.name)
    print("outfile {}".format(outfile))
    cc_library_outfile = actual_library[DefaultInfo].files.to_list()[0]

    print("outfile.path is {}".format(outfile.path))
    print("cc_library_outfile.path is {}".format(cc_library_outfile.path))

    ctx.actions.run_shell(
        inputs = [cc_library_outfile],
        outputs = [outfile],
        command = "cp %s %s" % (cc_library_outfile.path, outfile.path),
    )
    return [
        DefaultInfo(
              executable = outfile,
              data_runfiles = actual_library[DefaultInfo].data_runfiles,
        ),
    ]
```

sample output

```
DEBUG: /home/manesingh/work/DAI/minerva/examples-1/cpp-tutorial/stage3/defs.bzl:116:14: deps is ["@project//main:hello-greet", "//lib:hello-time"]

DEBUG: /home/manesingh/work/DAI/minerva/examples-1/cpp-tutorial/stage3/defs.bzl:22:10: actual_library <target //main:hello-greet_native_library>

DEBUG: /home/manesingh/work/DAI/minerva/examples-1/cpp-tutorial/stage3/defs.bzl:25:10: outfile <generated file main/hello-greet>

DEBUG: /home/manesingh/work/DAI/minerva/examples-1/cpp-tutorial/stage3/defs.bzl:28:10: outfile.path is bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/main/hello-greet

DEBUG: /home/manesingh/work/DAI/minerva/examples-1/cpp-tutorial/stage3/defs.bzl:29:10: cc_library_outfile.path is bazel-out/k8-fastbuild/bin/main/libhello-greet_native_library.a
```

Could someone help to figure this out?

Could someone help to figure this out?